# c - progress for each thread

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, progress

I've got a program that takes *n* numbers that generates a sum of each number from 0 to *N*. A new thread is created for each number given:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct sum_runner_struct {
    long long limit;
    long long answer;
};

// Thread function to generate sum of 0 to N
void* sum_runner(void* arg)
{
    struct sum_runner_struct *arg_struct = (struct sum_runner_struct*) arg;

    long long sum = 0;
    for (long long i = 0; i <= arg_struct->limit; i++) 
    {
        sum += i;
    }

    arg_struct->answer = sum;
    pthread_exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 2) 
    {
        printf("Usage: %s <num 1> <num 2> ... <num-n>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(-1);
    }
    int num_args = argc - 1;

    struct sum_runner_struct args[num_args];

    // Launch thread
    pthread_t tids[num_args];
    for (int i = 0; i < num_args; i++) 
    {
        args[i].limit = atoll(argv[i + 1]);
        pthread_attr_t attr;
        pthread_attr_init(&attr);
        pthread_create(&tids[i], &attr, sum_runner, &args[i]);
    }

    // Wait until thread is done its work
    for (int i = 0; i < num_args; i++) 
    {
        pthread_join(tids[i], NULL);
        printf("Sum for thread %d is %lld\n", i, args[i].answer);
    }
}
```

I want to display the progress of each thread (maybe in a percentage?) and from there I can calculate overall progress given each thread progress. I don't know how I can implement the progress for each thread though, how could I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be to add a global mutex, plus add a new member variable like `long long current_index` to your `sum_runner_struct`.

Every so often (e.g. maybe once every 1 million iterations of the for-loop?), each thread would then lock the mutex, set `arg_struct->current_index=i;`, and then unlock the mutex.

Then the main thread could then occasionally lock the mutex, iterate over the array `sum_runner_structs` to print out each thread's `current_index` value, and also tally up the sum of all of the values for the global-progress calculation, then unlock the mutex.